# How to filter limit year in datepicker?

Tags: android, datepicker

I want filter year in datepicker.
I.e.: filter appear 1960-2000, from >2000 disable or <1960 disable.

Can you help me?
I need it badly. the dealine being only 5 hour.

```
public void selectDate(final EditText edt) {
    date = c.get(Calendar.DATE);
    month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    year = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    datePickerDialog = new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), AlertDialog.THEME_HOLO_LIGHT, new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDateSet(DatePicker datePicker, int i, int i1, int i2) {
            c.set(i, i1, i2);
            yearPast = i;
            SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(myFormat);
            edt.setText(sdf.format(c.getTime()));
        }
    }, year, month, date);
    c.add(Calendar.YEAR, -18);
    datePickerDialog.getDatePicker().setMaxDate(c.getTimeInMillis());
    c.add(Calendar.YEAR, -42);
    datePickerDialog.getDatePicker().setMinDate(c.getTimeInMillis());
    Log.d("year", String.valueOf(year));
    datePickerDialog.show();
}
```

When click 1st true, 2st false

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 methods you can use for DatePicker class:  
`setMinDate()` and `setMaxDate()`
see the documentation: [https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/DatePicker](http://documentation)